# Insert and update Database to last shown activity

Tags: android, database, list, listview, offline

I have a simple problem (I think), that I cannot solve, even after much research. So for the first time I decided to post. I apologize if this is basic, or I cannot explain well. I'm a beginner.

I am devoloping a project, where I must connect to a database of movies, and get information through json.
At this point, I have my app running a list of playing now movies as other lists.
My goal (and problem) now is: **When offline, show the last list displayed on the screen.**
For that, I must somehow **save that list to a database** (I've never worked with db), and **delete and update to a new one** whenever i change screens on my app, so that the last list is displayed when online.
After that, I must **show that last saved list (updated db)**.
Questions: where to code for insert (update) database?
How to convert that list into a db class? I think  I must do that...
How to do the otherwise to insert that in a listview?
I use the same xml for that `ListView`? Since have the same params I think so...

So, here part of my code for this:

## Fragment

```
public class NowPlayingMoviesFragment extends BaseFragment{

    private ListView listMovies;
    private Button buttonGetMore;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    private int currentPage=1;
    private MovieAdapter movieAdapter;
    private ListView listOfflineMovies;



    public static NowPlayingMoviesFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        NowPlayingMoviesFragment fragment = new NowPlayingMoviesFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.now_playing_movies_fragment, container, false);
        findViews(v);
        executeNowPlayingMoviesRequest();
        addListeners();
        return v;
    }

    private void executeNowPlayingMoviesRequest() {
        new GetNowPlayingMoviesAsyncTask(getActivity(), String.valueOf(currentPage), getResources().getString(R.string.language)) {

            @Override
            protected void onResponseSuccess(MoviesResponse moviesResponse) {
                DLog.d(tag, "onResponseSuccess " + moviesResponse);
                // create the adapter

                if (movieAdapter != null) {
                    List<Movie> movies = moviesResponse.getMovies();
                    for (int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++) {
                        movieList.add(movies.get(i));
                    }
                    movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
**//is it here i save into db??**

                } else {
                    movieList = moviesResponse.getMovies();
                    movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
                    listMovies.setAdapter(movieAdapter);

            }

        }


        @Override
        protected void onNetworkError () {
            DLog.d(tag, "onNetworkError ");
            // Here i now that some error occur when processing the request,
            // possible my internet connection if turned off
            //OfflineMovieDbEntity();
            //MoviesItemDbEntity offlineMovies = new MoviesItemDbEntity(getActivity(),Movie.getOriginalTitle());
           // MoviesItemDbEntity offlineMovies = offlineMovies.findById(offLineMovies.class,1)
        }
    }.execute();
    }

    private void findViews(View v) {
        listMovies = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.now_playing_movies_list_view);
        buttonGetMore = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.get_more_button_movies_now);
        listOfflineMovies = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.offline_movies_screen_list_view);

    }

    private void addListeners() {

        buttonGetMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage=currentPage+1;
                executeNowPlayingMoviesRequest();
            }
        });


    }

}


---------------------------------------------------------------

# Movie Adapter #

public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

    public MovieAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<Movie> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View v;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        final Movie item = getItem(position);


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(v);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.movieTitle.setText(item.getTitle());

        //See movie details onclick

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MovieDetailsScreen.class);
                intent.putExtra("Movie", item);
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView movieTitle;


        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            movieTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.movie_item_title);


        }
    }

}

------------------------------------------------------------------------

#movie entitie#

public class Movie implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    private String posterPath;

    @SerializedName("overview")
    private String overview;

    @SerializedName("release_date")
    private String releaseDate;

    @SerializedName("original_title")
    private String originalTitle;

    @SerializedName("original_language")
    private String originalLanguage;

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    private String backdropPath;

    @SerializedName("popularity")
    private Double popularity;

    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    private Integer voteCount;

    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    private Double voteAverage;

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public String getOriginalTitle() {
        return originalTitle;
    }

    public String getOriginalLanguage() {
        return originalLanguage;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getBackdropPath() {
        return backdropPath;
    }

    public Double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public Integer getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }

    public Double getVoteAverage() {
        return voteAverage;
    }

    public Movie() {
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.posterPath);
        dest.writeString(this.overview);
        dest.writeString(this.releaseDate);
        dest.writeString(this.originalTitle);
        dest.writeString(this.originalLanguage);
        dest.writeString(this.title);
        dest.writeString(this.backdropPath);
        dest.writeValue(this.popularity);
        dest.writeValue(this.voteCount);
        dest.writeValue(this.voteAverage);
    }

    protected Movie(Parcel in) {
        this.posterPath = in.readString();
        this.overview = in.readString();
        this.releaseDate = in.readString();
        this.originalTitle = in.readString();
        this.originalLanguage = in.readString();
        this.title = in.readString();
        this.backdropPath = in.readString();
        this.popularity = (Double) in.readValue(Double.class.getClassLoader());
        this.voteCount = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
        this.voteAverage = (Double) in.readValue(Double.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Movie>() {
        @Override
        public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Movie(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movie[size];
        }
    };
}


-----------------------------------------------------------------
#movies response#

public class MoviesResponse {

    @SerializedName("page")
    private Integer page;

    @SerializedName("results")
    private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    private Integer totalPages;

    public Integer getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public Integer getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }

    public List<Movie> getMovies() {
        return movies;
    }
}


-----------------------------------------------------------

MovieAsyncTask

public abstract class GetNowPlayingMoviesAsyncTask extends ExecuteRequestAsyncTask<MoviesResponse> {

    private static final String PATH = "/movie/now_playing";
    private static final String LANGUAGE_KEY = "language";
    private static final String PAGE_KEY = "page";
    private String page;
    private String language;

    public GetNowPlayingMoviesAsyncTask(Context context, String page, String language) {
        super(context);
        this.page=page;
        this.language=language;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPath() {
        return PATH;
    }

    @Override
    protected void addQueryParams(StringBuilder sb) {
        addQueryParam(sb, LANGUAGE_KEY, language);
        addQueryParam(sb, PAGE_KEY, page);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<MoviesResponse> getResponseEntityClass() {
        return MoviesResponse.class;
    }

}

-----------------------------------------
#Movie Database#

public class MoviesItemDbEntity extends SugarRecord {
    public static final String TITLE_COLUMN_NAME = "movie_title_column";

    private String title;

    public MoviesItemDbEntity() {
    }

    public MoviesItemDbEntity(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }


    public String setTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}

---------------------------------------------------------

#Movie Item xml#

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_item_title"
        style="@style/ItemListStyle"
        android:text="lalalala"/>


</LinearLayout>

---------------------------------------------------------------
#now playing ListView xml#

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/now_playing_movies_title"
        style="@style/TitleStyle"
        android:text="@string/movies"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_more_button_movies_now"
        style="@style/ButtonMoreStyle"/>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/now_playing_movies_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/now_playing_movies_title">

    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Learn about SQLite database. Make fields corresponding to your model of the list item and store information in it whenever you receive it.

Comment: Sure you could add that movie information in SQLite DB but much easier would be just to save the json string you downloaded to local storage as a file. Start you app, if connectivity fails load the file from local storage.

Comment: It sounds like you are working on the first project for the Udacity Android Nanodegree, is this the case?

Comment: No. I'm taking a course about programming and developing for web and mobile. This is my third project, Android, the first one in mobile. The last one will be on ios. I love to dig and discover how the things working, but althougth Android is my favorite programming area, it's very different and more complicated to really understand how it works, phearps due to java. Needs many hours practing and coming here! :) But I love that!